# Modification of category template in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am having some trouble building the category template i want. Here is an example of one of my categories: http://transcorrect.bg/pi-de/category/versicherungen/

I want this field http://prntscr.com/k2d5xg to show posts only from the current category. I am attaching the code i am using right now, but it is only for specific category. What i want is to be on archive.php file as a code, that takes dynamically the category ID.

> Minimal example of code

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="headline-box" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Weitere Artikel</div>
    <?php
    // get the top-category posts
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'category_name' => 'Versicherungen',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    ));                                                                     
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div id="list-news-home" class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                <img src="http://transcorrect.bg/pi-de/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/arrow1.png" style="padding-right:20px;"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#00315C"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" style="float:right"> [ mehr ] </a>
            </div>                                                                   
            <hr style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:10px"> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>        
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to get it so if someone has made something similar i will be thankful to know how :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out.
If anyone needs similar thing i am posting how i converted the code i posted earlier.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="headline-box" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Weitere Artikel</div>
   <?php $current_cat_id  = get_query_var('cat'); $showposts = 10;
```

$args = array('cat' => $current_cat_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
             
         " style="color:#00315C">
         " style="float:right"> [ mehr ]

```
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```